# Regular expression to extract text from Dataframe and insert to new column

Tags: r, regex, string

I have been hunting through all the posts on regular expression and yet cannot seem to make this work for me.

Example of line (some words are redacted or changed)

---

Df$text: "CommonWord #79 - EVENT type for 1200 seconds [Objects] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/## xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/## Port: ##

1. I want to extract the numeric value after the # and place it in a new column
   I tried: df$number <- sub("\#([0-9]{2,4}).*", "\1", df$text)

   The result is "CommonWord 79" I cant seem to find the right regex to remove the first word.
2. The next regex I want to pull "EVENT type" and put into another column.  Both "EVENT" and "type" can change so I would need to pull text after the "- " and before the " for".
3. 4. The last two regexes I need are for the the IP addresses and subnet mask and then the port number (number only).  I need all of this to new columns.

---

Sorry for the long winded question.  Been beating my head on this one

---

Resolved part 1, the Event Type and Port needs

```
df$number <- sub(".*\\#(\\d{1,4}).*", "\\1", df$text)
df$attackType <- sub(".*\\-.(\\w+\\s\\w+).*","\\1", df$text)
df$port <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\:(\\d{1, })?","\\1", df$text))
```

---

having some issues with finding the IP addresses (only getting the first digit in the first set of numbers.  example actual ip is 127.0.0.1/28 but im getting 7.0.0.1/28 returned.  After figuring out how to get the IP address/mask i need to determine how i find more than one result in the text
lengthy regex - looking to optimize later

```
df$IPs <- sub(".*(+\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/\\d{2, }).*","\\1", df$text)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you just had to add ".*" to indicate any #character before the number

```
sub(".*\\#([0-9]{2,4}).*", "\\1", x)
```

# to create a new column

```
 df$new_col <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\#([0-9]{2,4}).*", "\\1", df$text))
```

Comment: Thanks for the as.numeric!  I was able to get the sub to work as you suggested with one change
regex was:  ".*\\#(\\d{1,4}).*"

now need to figure out the other needs.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Are those `x` supposed to represent numbers? Some values would help, especially given that IP addresses don't follow exactly that pattern.

Anyway, I've added in something to search against. I like to use the `rex` package in combination with `stringr::str_view_all` to test regex patterns. Results are highlighted in the Viewer pane.

```
text <- "CommonWord #79 - EVENT type for 1200 seconds [Objects] 192.168.0.24/## xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/## Port: 80"
library(stringr)
library(rex)

# show matches where at least one digit follows #
str_view_all(text, rex(at_least(digit, 1) %if_prev_is% "#"))

# show matches where characters are after - and before 'for'
str_view_all(text, rex((prints %if_prev_is% "-") %if_next_is% "for"))

# show matches the x in your IP text match 1-3 digits, and end with /
str_view_all(text, rex(between(digit, 1, 3), dot, 
                       between(digit, 1, 3), dot, 
                       between(digit, 1, 3), dot, 
                       between(digit, 1, 3), "/"))

# show matches where digits follow 'Port:'
str_view_all(text, rex(digits %if_prev_is% "Port: "))
```

Comment: x does represent numbers, i redacted for privacy reasons but assume its an IP address, meaning it four sets of number ranging from 1 - 254.  Example 127.0.0.1, etc.